# Microcontroller power dissipation

Tags: microcontroller

I wanted to know how to calculate the power dissipation of a micro-controller. If I have the information on which pin is sourcing how much current, how can i calculate the power dissipation of the MCU? Also i would like to know how this power dissipation varies with frequency and calculations for the same.

Comment: It's in the datasheet and will vary a bit per MCU. Which one do you use?

Comment: I am going for PIC's PIC10F200T. Yeah i agree that it varies with microconrtoller as the sourcing current varies from MCU tyo MCU. But i juat wanted know how the calculaitons can be done for the powerdissipation.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to look in the data sheet to determine how much power is consumed inside the processor itself. This will almost certainly be a function of the clock frequency but it may also depend on which peripheral devices you are using inside the processor. There may be tables or graphs in addition to some kind of worst-case specification.

Second, add the power used to drive the processor pins. If the load on a pin is capacitive, like the gate of some CMOS logic device, then the power consumption is equal to \$C_{LOAD}f_{SWITCH}V^2\$ where \$f_{SWITCH}\$ is the frequency that the load is switched, not the CPU clock frequency. If the load is resistive then there is a d.c. component as well. Calculate the power consumed by each output pin and add it to the internal power consumption, and you have your answer.